# iPhone: Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK installation failure

Tags: iphone

I want to update my Xcode with iOS 5 SDK. I have a snow leopard macbook. I have download the sdk file from the Apple link using my active and correct Apple registered login credentials.
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg

Its downloading a 1.64 GB .dmg file finally. But, every time when i tried to installed, it says, "The following disk image couldn't be opened, ode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg not recognized"

I tried more than 10 times, all the times it is same. I'm using my very active and proper Apple registered account.

Looks like there are many people facing the same issue recently.

How can i update my SDK to 5.0? Please share your ideas and give me if you find any direct SDK links from somewhere else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1.64GB seems pretty little... I think it should be around 4GB... your download must have got broken, unfortunately...

Comment: No. You can even try now by clicking this link http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg      it clearly says 1.64 GB when downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a corrupt file. The download must have failed. Try to download using a download manager like [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html).

Using my own account I found the following link:

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg

See if that works better.

Comment: OK, i'll try using igetter, Thanks so much!